# OneVsRestClassifier with n_jobs > 1 stuck with zero percent cpu usage for all jobs

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit a rather large dataset (~10 million samples, 15 features) using SVC. When I run it as a single job it appears to run fine, but after several hours it is still not done. I have a remote connection to a workstation with 40 logical cores and 125 Gigs of memory, so it should be straightforward to transfer my code and data to that machine and use either the `BaggingClassifier` or the `OneVsRestClassifier` and then set `n_jobs=-1` or `n_jobs=10`. However when I do that, a lot of new python proccesses are created, each with identical memory usage, but all of them are stuck at zero percent cpu usage. Any idea what is going on?

This is my code. The shape of `data` is `(10046977, 15)`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

data = np.loadtxt('training.csv', header=None, dtype=float, usecols=range(2,17))
types = np.loadtxt('training.csv', header=None, dtype=str, usecols=(17,))

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100), n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(data[:], types[:])
```

## EDIT

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 for this particular issue.

Comment: Can you try with a smaller dataset and `n_jobs=-1`, to check if its working or not. Also, you can try setting `verbose=True` in SVC to check the progress. One more thing, SVMs work fast with standardised data, can you check if your data is standardised or not.

Comment: @VivekKumar it appears that every new job created goes straight to sleep. When setting `n_jobs=-1` IDLE pops up with about 39 warnings that my program is still running and asks if I want to kill it. `verbose=True` is not really giving me any output. When I had only one job, it gave me the following: `[LibSVM]` and nothing else. Running multiple jobs have not given me any output as of yet. I am currently trying with a 100.000 sample dataset without any luck.

Comment: @VivekKumar just to update you, a dataset of 1000 samples with `n_jobs=-1` is also stuck.

Comment: Have you standardized the data? Well, I'm sorry but this kind of thing is very hard to debug, because it depends a lot on the OS, hardware, the versions of libraries, their interactions (like numpy and MKL, OPENMP). You can [check here for solutions](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=erM&channel=fs&ei=R9I9W4vFEpiSvQSP0b-gDA&q=n_jobs+%22svc%22+stuck+hang+freeze+github.com+scikit-learn&oq=n_jobs+%22svc%22+stuck+hang+freeze+github.com+scikit-learn&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21965.23365.0.23628.2.2.0.0.0.0.126.244.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.geH8w4hmAB8)

Comment: @VivekKumar All features are normalized to be either in the range `[0;1]` or `[-1,1]`, if that's what you mean. I'm running it on Ubuntu Xenial with an Intel Xeon CPU and running Python 3.5.2 with the latest versions of all packages. I have tried Googling for solutions, but I have not been able to find anything that resembles my issue so far.

Comment: @VivekKumar I've done some more searching and it appears that this is an issue related to the `multiprocessing` library on UNIX-type systems like OSX and Linux. The fix is to set the environmentvariable `JOBLIB_START_METHOD` to `'forkserver'` rather than its UNIX default `'fork'`. Windows, apparently does not support that default and therefore the issue never occurs on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**I had similar problems and I managed to solve it by using the following:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

if __name__ =='main':
    data = np.loadtxt('training.csv', header=None, dtype=float, usecols=range(2,17))
    types = np.loadtxt('training.csv', header=None, dtype=str, usecols=(17,))

    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100), n_jobs=-1)
    clf.fit(data[:], types[:])
```

Comment: Did you change anything besides adding an `if` statement?`I figured out the issue on my end was related to the way linux handles multiple jobs.

Comment: No but this is what it made it work on Windows for me.

Comment: fair enough. I probably should have mentioned the OS of my system. It just never occured to me that there would be a difference, since I was using Python.